# Receive all of the data when using python socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am using socket to connect to a simple server to receive some data:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "X.X.X.X"
port = Y
s.connect((host,port))

data = s.recv(512)
print data
```

Not all of the expected received data is received; some of it is cut off. So any operations that I need to perform on the received data is thrown off.

I've tried using `s.settimeout(1)` and putting the socket in non-blocking mode. Strangely, it works just fine in ipython.

Comment: use a loop to read until the connection is closed by the other side. Or create a simple protocol where you send the amount of bytes to be read and then read in a loop until you have that many bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Even if 512 bytes are sent from the server to the client, if they're sent through multiple packets, and that one packet has TCP Push flag set, the kernel will stop buffering and hand over the data to userland, ie, your application.

You should loop on data = s.recv(512) and print data.  I'd even remove the '512', which is useless.

```
while True:
    if not data: break
    data = s.recv()
    print data
```