# Can't decode string to image using Base64

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp, base64

In a android application I'm building, I convert the jpg image to string using Base64.encodeToString() and sending to a server via TCP socket.

The problem is when I try to decode the string back to the image.
I can print the string that I receive, it looks like this at the end of the file(The only part I can copy because the file is to big to print everything on the terminal):

```
....+77DgjRKHqbxBmYCDOzv9vLzFwff4N146snCWin6ZlzbN++HJOIIPodB/JTOoc1NjczeqoHwOju
iWdI6ePeSO0ADz46vh4LODnM7FCJYhbTX0TizmNatXvxSFoVzLiqfn19iYjvAPD/AQnRoUxtpJij
AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

But when I try to decode and save into a jpg file again I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tcp.py", line 20, in <module>
    file.write(base64.decodestring(msg))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 328, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Here is a piece of my Android application code used to encode and send the message:

```
//Function that encodes the Bitmapfile into string
    public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] arr=baos.toByteArray();
        String result=Base64.encodeToString(arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return result;
    }

    class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        //Faz a conexao entre aparelho e servidor
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){

            try
            {
                //create socket and buffer to send the string message
                newSocket = new Socket(ipAdress,5000);
                printWriter = new PrintWriter(newSocket.getOutputStream());
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(newSocket.getOutputStream()));

                //Reads the internal storage image and converts into string using Base64
                File file  = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+"/Reccoon3D/123.jpg");
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                message = BitMapToString(bitmap); //encodes the bitmap
                //sends the enconded image
                bufferedWriter.write(message);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                newSocket.close();
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And here is my python code that receives the message and try to decode it to image again:

```
import socket
import base64 

host = '192.168.1.16'
port = 5000
tcp=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
orig = (host,port)
tcp.bind(orig)
tcp.listen(1)
file=open('file.png','wb')

while True:
    con, client = tcp.accept()
    print('Conected by', client)
    while True:
        msg = con.recv(1024000) #Initially 1024 but changet so the message
                                #would not be sliced into pieces
        if not msg: break
        #print(msg)
        file.write(base64.decodestring(msg))

    print('Finalizado com sucesso')
    con.close
```

Comment: Didn't you miss some (at most 2) `=` chars at the end of the *base64* blob?

Comment: Check first if the amount of bytes sent are equal to the amount of bytes received. Please tell the amounts.

Comment: `recv´ is not guaranteed to return all data at once, even if you give a large size. Possible duplicate of [Receive all of the data when using python socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953626/receive-all-of-the-data-when-using-python-socket)

Comment: `I convert the jpg image to string`. No. Not at all. You convert a jpg image to a bitmap. Then the bitmap to a png. Then you base64 encode the png.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     msg = con.recv(1024000) #Initially 1024 but changet so the message
> ```

This will read **up to** 1024000 bytes from the socket. It might be less than this. And, the size of the chunks read using `recv` do not need to have any correlation with the  size of the chunks written by the peer, apart from that the total size read over all `recv` matches the total size sent.

> ```
>     file.write(base64.decodestring(msg))
> ```

A base64 string has always a size which is a multiple of 4 bytes. Even if the decoded data are only one byte the encoded string will be 4 bytes: 2 encoding the input and 2 '=' for padding. If the length of the string used with `decodestring` is not a multiple of 4 it will assume a bad padding, i.e. raise `binascii.Error: Incorrect padding`.

Your code blindly assumes that the length of `msg` will always be a multiple of 4 since you kind of assume that `recv` will return all data sent. But, this assumption is wrong and if the length of `msg` is not a multiple of 4 you get the error you see.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the exact same thing that you said.

> In a android application I'm building, I convert the jpg image to
>   string using Base64.encodeToString() and sending to a server via TCP
>   socket.

And I finally got it.

First I used as template [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) project. Here you are able to take a snap and then load it as a BitMap. Then you have to convert that into a byte array coded as PNG file, then encode it through base64 algorithm (that is already implemented in Java).

Then I made a socket server with python and some other stuff to handle the transmision. Once you get the coded string, you only have to decode it and save the resulting string as a .png file then load it with `cv2.imread()` and Vuala!

Here are my projects if you want to check how I did it:
[Android side](https://github.com/tonyre4/runasAndroid) 
[Python side](https://github.com/applied-data-mining-master/unidad-2-actividad-4-runas-maestria)